# Full-featured Windows-based Android file explorer

Tags: windows, android, file-management

It is more convenient and easier to search and manage some files from a PC than on an Android using an Android file explorer (such as [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer)).

I have tried a lot of PC Android helper programs (made in China). They do have similar function, but lack superpower features:

- Search file from `/`.
- Drag PC folder/files to an Android directory in the file browser.
- Support Windows shortcut, such as <kbd>Delete</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
- Sort paths by metadata, such as `creation time`, `last modification time`.

… because they are mainly working as app market. (Google Play is blocked in China, so there is a lot local software producers want to be the mobile app entry and develop such things. I think they are a little like iTunes but much more powerful for idiot with many functional tools embedded, for idiot make them contain some properties of rogue software, that's why I don't want to use them.)

So I want to find a pure (no extra features besides file manager) and full power Android file manager for PC.

Of course it should use root permissions. My Android is rooted.

Comment: What about a (S)FTP server on your Android device and a (S)FTP client on your Windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

[QtADB](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/) does not satisfy all requirements, but a good part of them:

- Show root
- Copy/rename/etc
- Sort files by metadata
- Works on Windows/Linux/Mac
- Free and [open source](https://github.com/triochi/QtAdb)

Unfortunately no CTRL-C/etc shortcuts and no search.

[image: QtADB explorer]